# How can Android be made to stop showing Google Contacts information?

Tags: google-contacts

How can Android be made to stop showing Google Contacts information? The title is sufficient to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to prevent turn off the "Contact Sync" off
Goto Settings -> Goto Sync -> Select Google -> Select the Google Account email id if you have multiple accounts logged in.

Uncheck the Contacts so that it would not sync.

[image]

Now open Contacts App and open Settings of Contact app. Select Hide Incomplete Numbers (As most google synced contact would have only email id not numbers so they will be hidden)

That's how I guess it can be achieved

[image]